# Working with HTTP POST request with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I'm developing a jsp which sends POST requests to a servlet. I would like to write content in raw payload instead of key-value form.

```
var addItemApp = angular.module('addItem',[]);
addItemApp.controller('addItemCtrl', function($scope, $http){
    $scope.addItemBnClicked = function(){
        var rqst = $http.post('http://127.0.0.1:8180/JSP/ws', "This is a test content");

        rqst.success(function(rspnData, status, headers, config){
            alert("Status: " + status);
        });

    }
});
```

Checking on the server side, I found that the payload doesn't contain anything. Please help, Thanks. ^^

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Edit %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

I use the following code to get the payload.

```
String line = "";
String rqstRawBody = "";
while((line = servletRqst.getReader().readLine()) != null){
    rqstRawBody += line;
}

System.out.println("rqstRawBody: " + rqstRawBody);
```

The `rqstRawBody` is finally an empty string. I believe the above java code is okay, as I get raw payload correctly for those requests sent using the chrome-app Rest Client.

Comment: the function is ok which type of data you are recieving in server side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should [change the Content-Type HTTP header](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#setting-http-headers). By default Angular sets that to `application/json` for a POST request.

```
var config = { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' } };
var data = { someKey: 'SomeValue'};
$http.post('/url', data, config).then(...);
```

Or you can set it as the default for all requests as shown in the documentation:

```
module.run(function($http) {
  $http.defaults.headers.common['Content-Type']= 'text/plain'
});
```

Comment: @chunchiuChan look at edit, it was missing with `data` option.